# Spring form radiobutton passing two values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and got stuck with changing an application with jstl spring tags. Currently there is a solution with two radiobuttons - button1 which passes value1 to path "A" and button2 which passes value2 to path "A".

What I need to do is to add an extra radiobutton (button3). The goal is for the both button1 and button3 to pass value1 to path "A" while simultaneously button1 would pass value3 to path "B" and button3 would pass value4 to path "B".

Is it possible with just spring jstl tags? If so, how can this be done?

```
<ul>                        
                <li>
                    <label class="someclass">
                        <form:radiobutton path="A" value="1"/>
                        <span for="something"> <spring:message code="source.msg1" /> </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="someclass">
                        <form:radiobutton path="A" value="2" />
                        <span for="something"> <spring:message code="source.msg2" /> </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show the code what you have done and show where you are stuck

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your need. It's not well explained. If you detail it, it will be great :)